# Auto convert CSS "longhand" into "shorthand" in Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: css, firefox, browser, firefox-developer-tools, code-inspection

In Firebug, CSS would automatically be converted from longhand into shorthand.

Example:

```
div {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

}
```

would then be converted by Firebug into:

```
div {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

However, now when I use Firefox Developer Tools, there is no auto CSS shorthand conversion.

[image: Screenshot from "Firefox Developer Tools"]

Is it possible to get the new Firefox Developer Tools to automatically convert longhand CSS into shorthand CSS (like how Firebug does)?

Comment: 2 and 3 are too broad and subjective for Stack Overflow. Firebug is EOL anyway so if you want to stick with that then you won't be getting any updates. The only answer to 3 is whichever works best for you. Try them all. Or... just stick with Firebug if you're really attached to it.

Comment: Those two code blocks are **not** equivalent.

Comment: I updatede the example code in hope that Everyone will understand what I am asking.

I could try out all the different dev tools - and see whichever works best for me(!)... 
But what I'm really looking for is a list of reasons (objective) why "x codeinspector" is better than "y codeinspector".

No reason to reinvent the wheel

Comment: But "better" is subjective. You may prefer Firebug's way of condensing longhands into shorthands, but others may prefer the WYSIWYG approach taken by just about every browser's built-in tools.

Comment: A ferrari is better than a transporter in regards of speed.
A transporter is better than a ferrari in terms of loading capacity.

"X" is better than "Y" beacuse of "Z".

I'm sure someone on stackoverflow has the answer I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the Firefox DevTools. It's by design that the DevTools display the property declarations as they were entered. One reason for that is because they indicate which declarations were changed by the user (via a small green line at the left side of the declaration).

Firebug, on the other hand, output what's returned by the [`CSSRule.cssText` API](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssrule-csstext), which outputs a serialization of the CSS rule and turns longhands into shorthands where possible. So, Firebug did the opposite of the Firefox DevTools and always displayed the shortened version of a CSS rule were applicable and there was no way to show them the way they were authored.

So, if you want to get a short version of your CSS rules, you need to call its `cssText` getter via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Firefox Developer Tools displays properties exactly as they are declared in each rule in the stylesheet; in that sense, it doesn't display properties *per se*, it displays *declarations*.

If the rule has a `padding` shorthand declaration, the inspector reflects that shorthand (and allows you to expand that shorthand into its longhands so you can manipulate them individually). If the rule has two of four longhand declarations for `padding`, the inspector reflects just those two longhands.

This is by design, and prevents the sort of confusion that automatically rewriting longhands into shorthands for the sake of brevity creates (namely, the fact that `padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px` is *not* equivalent to `padding: 10px 0`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding declarations (!)

I updated the code example.

I want the automatic conversion to shorthand just because i'm missing the firebug feature since i used it alot.
- What code inspector are you using and why did you pick it?

Comment: @guruguldmand: I just use the built-in one for every browser.

Comment: Note that Firebug actually only displayed what it retrieved through the internal Firefox API `document.styleSheets[x].cssRules[y].style.cssText`. This API returns a [serialized version of the CSS rule with longhands merged into shorthands](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssrule-csstext) where possible. Therefore Firebug did not produce inequivalent output. This means, only when all four padding-* longhands are specified they get rewritten into the shorthand. See https://jsfiddle.net/6787L25t/ for example. Therefore you should remove your note in brackets.